# binary split and the options

Tags: erlang

Why is this function returning 3 elements ?

```
[<<"12345">>,<<"67890">>,<<>>]


test3()->
    test4(<<"12345\r\n67890\r\n">>).
test4(Data)->
    X = binary:split(Data, [<<"\r\n">>],[global]), 
    X.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
binary:split(Subject,Pattern,Options)
```

will split the binary object into the part of the binary that is before the splitting delimiter, and the parts after.

Consider adding the trim options for the binary:split, i.e.

```
binary:split(Data, [<<"\r\n">>],[trim,global]),
```

Comment: You are right ! thank you. According to the doc I thought it was global or trim but not both.